# Why Augment Reality does not work well in Portrait orientation

Tags: windows-phone-7

As above, I need some help on AR for my windows phone. The below code is what I used:

Orientation : Portrait

XAML :

```
 <Rectangle Margin="0,44,0,178">
     <Rectangle.Fill>
         <videoBrush x:Name="videoBrush" />
     </Rectangle.Fill>
 </Rectangle>
```

Code being XAML :

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    cam = new PhotoCamera();         

    videoBrush.SetSource(cam);
}
```

Problems:

1) I am holding the Phone Upright but the VideoBrush does not show image in portrait position. The image is like in Landscape.  What do I need to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I need to use Motion API.  Thanks